# LNK 1104: cannot open file ...exe. But it doesn't even create an exe File

Tags: c++, build, linker, exe, fatal-error

So I am using Visual Studio 19. I just started a new plain C++ project. It builds and I can run it.
But after changing anything within the code, the next time it would not build and rather yield the following:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Test.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'F:\...\Test\Test\Debug\Test.exe'
1>Done building project "Test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Even after changing everything back to the original code, I get the exact same result.
After a PC restart, I still get this output. Even when I then create a new project again I get that error. After some time it randomly worked again, but once I changed something it broke again.
I could not reproduce this and the behaviour seems to be irregular.

But I also do not have any exe file within my Debug folder (only the first time, when the build succeeded.)

Most websites suggest:
Either the exe is still running, or the includes are misspelt. But since this is the default hello world program and it worked once, it cannot be the latter. And it is also not the former one because, after a PC restart, I still got the error message.

Comment: This eror can happen if you have the program either running or open in the debugger when IDE tries to link it as the linker cannot overwrite a running program.  Also Virus checkers can cause this for the same reason as they open the file to scan it.

Comment: Okay it might be the Windows Defender then. But how do I check or fix that? Adding an Exception for all .exe files doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: You can add a folder exception for you development tree.

Comment: “Open” can include “create” in programming (as opposed to GUI elements), and that’s what it means here.

Comment: Thank you all! Adding an exception for my antivirus helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as pointed out by Richard it actually was the antivirus that ran my application in the background.
I fixed it by simply adding an exception for the whole application folder.